An error occurred while installing psych (5.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue
An error occurred while installing psych (5.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
In Gemfile:
  debug was resolved to 1.9.2, which depends on
    irb was resolved to 1.13.1, which depends on
      rdoc was resolved to 6.6.3.1, which depends on
        psych
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Writing lockfile to D:/railsfriends/friends/Gemfile.lock
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find importmap-rails-2.0.1, turbo-rails-2.0.5, stimulus-rails-1.3.3,
debug-1.9.2, web-console-4.2.1, irb-1.13.1, rdoc-6.6.3.1, psych-5.1.2 in locally
installed gems
       rails  importmap:install
Could not find importmap-rails-2.0.1, turbo-rails-2.0.5, stimulus-rails-1.3.3, debug-1.9.2, web-console-4.2.1, irb-1.13.1, rdoc-6.6.3.1, psych-5.1.2 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Could not find importmap-rails-2.0.1, turbo-rails-2.0.5, stimulus-rails-1.3.3, debug-1.9.2, web-console-4.2.1, irb-1.13.1, rdoc-6.6.3.1, psych-5.1.2 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

This exactly is the error message.
I tried all the stuffs but still doesn't work for me.

Ruby version- 3.1.2p20
Rails version- 7.1.3.2

I tried all the solutions suggested in the article but couldn't resolve the installation error. This error is coming while running the command rails new 'file_name'. It is depending on the pysch which i want to install.

This seems to be a persistent issue with windows installs -- here are some suggestions mostly related to a yaml library dependency. https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/cant-setup-rails-psych-yaml-issue/83968/15

You don't say if you ran the suggestions in the error message (run  bundle lock --add..., run  bundle binstubs bundler, etc.) and it says "Run bundle install to install missing gems" did you do that? And if so, what is the output?

I'm getting this same issue. Running on WSL (debian). Installed ruby, installed rails (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application) ran rails new blog and got the psych issue.

I had the same Problem on Debian 12 with Rails 7.1.3.3 - after a little research I figured out this problem is a bit older and for Linux Distributions just needed to install a YAML lib.
Debian / Ubuntu: apt-get install libyaml-dev
Then the Rails tutorial works fine

I am on windows 11 and gem install psych solved the problem for me.

For AmazonLinux (CentOS), I solved it by yum install libyaml-devel.
